# Apply style to child in server control

Tags: c#, css, styles, styling, servercontrols

I have a server control that I've created that allows custom content inside of it.  This custom content all resides inside a div, which I call contentDiv.  What I would like to do is pass any style attributes placed on the server control to the contentDiv.  When I try doing this by overriding the style property, it seems that the property is never called.  Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: What you're asking for is a parent selector, which currently doesn't exist in CSS (being considered by W3 etc. I believe). The only way to assign style to a parent is through javascript

Comment: @AdamBotley I'm not sure it's actually a selector I'm looking for.  I'm just looking for a way to forward the property through overrides